# DB2 query not working

Tags: query, db2, subquery

**Customer** (parent table)

| Id | Charge Amt |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 10 |
| C2 | 20 |
| C3 | 30 |
| C4 | 40 |

**Payment** (child table)

| Id | pymt amt |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 10 |
| C2 | 5 |
| C4 | 40 |

Select Id and pending balance from customer and payment tables

Pending balance validations:

1. If payment amount is >= charge amount then set pending balances to 0
2. If payment amount is less then set charge amount - payment amount to pending balance.
3. If payment record not found then set charge amount to pending balances.

My query is not working for third(3) scenario:

I need output like:

| Id | Pending bal |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 0 |
| C2 | 15 |
| C3 | 30 |
| C4 | 0 |

Query: Tried left outer join also but sum of payment is not working.

```
Select A.ID,
       (SELECT (
        CASE
        WHEN (SUM(B.PYMT AMT) < A.CHARGE AMT)
        THEN (A.CHARGE AMT - SUM(B.PYMT AMT))
        ELSE 0 END)
        FROM PYMT B
        WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
FROM CUST A;
```

Comment: Please edit your message to show us your query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta pls check my query i tried.

Comment: @ErgestBasha , you should make that an answer.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple payments for the same customer?

Answer (score 1):

A simple case without any aggregation function is needed.

```
select c.Id,
       case when p.pymtamt >= c.ChargeAmt then 0
            when p.pymtamt <  c.ChargeAmt then c.ChargeAmt-p.pymtamt
            when p.pymtamt is null then c.ChargeAmt end as Pendingbal
from Customer c
left join Payment p on c.Id=p.Id;
```

1.If payment amount is >= charge amount then set pending balances to 0

```
when p.pymtamt >= c.ChargeAmt then 0
```

2.If payment amount is less then set charge amount - payment amount to pending balance.

```
when p.pymtamt <  c.ChargeAmt then c.ChargeAmt-p.pymtamt
```

3.If payment record not found then set charge amount to pending balances.

```
when p.pymtamt is null then c.ChargeAmt
```

pymtamt when doesn't exist will be null because of the left join.

*Note*, the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gkz3WJwi) is tested using MySQL , when choosing DB2 it didn't display any records

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple payments for the same customer.

```
select 
  c.Id
, decode (sign (c.ChargeAmt - coalesce(p.pymtamt, 0)), -1, 0, c.ChargeAmt - coalesce(p.pymtamt, 0))
  as Pendingbal
from Customer c
left join 
(
  select Id, sum (pymtamt) as pymtamt
  from Payment
  group by Id
) p on c.Id=p.Id
order by c.Id
```

| ID | PENDINGBAL |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 0 |
| C2 | 15 |
| C3 | 30 |
| C4 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TbnOSrJv)